# SQL query via macro / VBA, 64-bit MS Office users get, what looks like credentials prompt window, but no such for 32-bit MS Office users

Tags: sql, vba, excel, 64-bit

I have a simple SQL query (below) that I run via a macro in Excel workbook. It works fine on MS Office 32-bit as well as 64-bit, however, for 64-bit Office users a pop-up window (below) appears in the middle (on the `.Refresh` line). It is enough to just press "OK" and the macro continues and fetches the data correctly, however, I would like to avoid this pop-up window if possible and/or understand why this is happening, please?

Query:

```
Sub Run_Query( _
ByRef SQL_Data_rng As Range, _
ByRef Conn_str As String, _
ByRef SQL_str As String)

    With ws1.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:="" & Conn_str & "", _
    Destination:=SQL_Data_rng, _
    Sql:=SQL_str)
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: Pop Up window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I found the cause of the problem. There was a mistake deeper in my code that I didn’t mention. I'm going to post my findings here, hopefully it will help someone in the future.

I store my Connection and SQL query info in a worksheet and to get these into a string I'm using a small function.

```
Function BuildStr(Rng As Range) As String
    Dim Sub_Str As Range
    For Each Sub_Str In Rng
        BuildStr = BuildStr & Sub_Str & vbNewLine
    Next Sub_Str
End Function
```

The `& vbNewLine` is there to ensure SELECT, FROM, WHERE, etc. statements in my SQL string start from new lines (otherwise no dice) and it also makes it easier to read the query when occasionally printed out. 
But looks like it should not be used in the Connection string.

So in short, the connection string should look like this:

```
OLEDB;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=SVR_name;Database=DB_name;Trusted_Connection=Yes
```

And not like this:

```
OLEDB; & VbNewLine & DRIVER=SQL Server;  & VbNewLine & SERVER=SVR_name;  & VbNewLine & Database=DB_name;  & VbNewLine & Trusted_Connection=Yes
```

I am yet to understand why this isn't an issue on 32-bit Office, but most importantly I got rid of the annoying pop-up window (and learned something I didn't know).

Thanks,
J.

Answer (score 1):

As `Conn_str` is already a string, you don't need to quote it (actually: shouldn't quote it):

```
Connection:= Conn_str, ...
```

Comment: Good point, thank you, I've updated my code now (but with no effect on that pop-up window)